# Evenly space UIImageViews within UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uiimageview, constraints

I have a UIScrollview in my VC containing 9 image views with a size of 25px x 25 px on an iphone 5s they are perfectly spaced in the centre of the scroll view. when ran on an iphone 6 they are pushed over to the left, not stretching evenly across the screen, due to the screen size.

is there a way i can make them evenly spaced on both screen sizes?

Code Below:

> ```
> // Set up ScrollView
>
>
> NSLog(@"%f", self.view.frame.size.width);
>
> UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(25, 200, self.view.frame.size.width - 50, 30)];
>
> scrollView.alwaysBounceHorizontal = YES;
>
> NSLog(@"%f", scrollView.frame.size.width);
>
> UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, scrollView.frame.size.width, scrollView.frame.size.height)];
> [scrollView addSubview:view];
>
> UIImage *star = [UIImage imageNamed:@"badge_star"];
> UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:star];
> imgView.frame = CGRectMake(2.5, 5, 25, 25);
> [view addSubview:imgView];
>
> UIImage *target= [UIImage imageNamed:@"badge_target"];
> UIImageView *targetImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:target];
> targetImageView.frame = CGRectMake(32.5, 5, 25, 25);
> [view addSubview:targetImageView];
>
> UIImage *crown = [UIImage imageNamed:@"badge_crown"];
> UIImageView *crownImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:crown];
> crownImageView.frame = CGRectMake(62.5, 5, 25, 25);
> [view addSubview:crownImageView];
>
> UIImage *scissors = [UIImage imageNamed:@"badge_scissors"];
> UIImageView *scissorsImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:scissors];
> scissorsImageView.frame = CGRectMake(92.5, 5, 25, 25);
> [view addSubview:scissorsImageView];
>
> UIImage *thumbsup = [UIImage imageNamed:@"badge_thumbs_up"];
> UIImageView *thumbsupImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:thumbsup];
> thumbsupImageView.frame = CGRectMake(122.5, 5, 25, 25);
> [view addSubview:thumbsupImageView];
>
> UIImage *trophy = [UIImage imageNamed:@"badge_trophy"];
> UIImageView *trophyImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:trophy];
> trophyImageView.frame = CGRectMake(152.5, 5, 25, 25);
> [view addSubview:trophyImageView];
>
> UIImage *medal = [UIImage imageNamed:@"badge_medal"];
> UIImageView *medalImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:medal];
> medalImageView.frame = CGRectMake(182.5, 5, 25, 25);
> [view addSubview:medalImageView];
>
> UIImage *heart = [UIImage imageNamed:@"badge_heart"];
> UIImageView *heartImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:heart];
> heartImageView.frame = CGRectMake(212.5, 5, 25, 25);
> [view addSubview:heartImageView];
>
> UIImage *coathanger = [UIImage imageNamed:@"badge_coathanger"];
> UIImageView *coathangerImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:coathanger];
> coathangerImageView.frame = CGRectMake(242.5, 5, 25, 25);
> [view addSubview:coathangerImageView];
>
> [self.view addSubview:scrollView]; 
>
> }
> ```

Comment: You're using constant positions for the image view frames. You should be calculating it based on the width of the entire view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because you are hard coding the start point of scroll view. You have two option;
 1. Increase the spacing between each image    OR
2. Change the start point of scroll view
Opting for 2nd option is relatively easy in your code. Use the below code for your scroll view frame.

```
float scrollViewWidth = 25*9+5*8+2*2.5; // Cross check this one.  
float xScrollPoint = (self.view.frame.size.width - scrollViewWidth)/2  

UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xScrollPoint, 200, scrollViewWidth, 30)];
```

Comment: obviously, i wrote that in text file and forgot to remove []. See the edited code.